# How can I call Django's manage.py from GNOME Builder?

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv, gnome-builder

I have GNOME Builder installed on 3.24.1 installed on Ubuntu 17.04. I have a functional Django project and an associated virtualenv. (Django 1.11, Python 3)

How can I configure Builder, so that when I click Run it invokes `manage.py runserver` in the virtualenv? (Ideally I'd like to be able to run other `manage.py` functions too, like `manage.py collectstatic`.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not really possible as Gnome-Builder works tightly integrated with flatpak. As far as I know the "hostsystem buildsystem" only supports auto detected run targets and only one of those.

However if you create a flatpak json manifest you can set the command to be run in the `command` variable of the `json` manifest - though probably not everything you want. As this means the application runs in a flatpak sandbox.

## Setup

To do that you can create a new python gnome application with gnome-builder called `djangoproj`. This will generate a Project that uses the meson buildsystem and a `org.gnome.djangoproj.json`. The next thing would be to remove the gnome application - or you just ignore it and add your Django dependencies.

Add the required modules **before** the native modules. For just Django this is:

```
[…]
"modules" : [
    {
        "name": "python3-Django",
        "buildsystem": "simple",
        "build-commands": [
            "pip3 install --no-index --find-links=\"file://${PWD}\" --prefix=${FLATPAK_DEST} Django"
        ],
        "sources": [
            {
                "type": "file",
                "url": "https://pypi.python.org/packages/1b/50/4cdc62fc0753595fc16c8f722a89740f487c6e5670c644eb8983946777be/pytz-2018.3.tar.gz",
                "sha256": "410bcd1d6409026fbaa65d9ed33bf6dd8b1e94a499e32168acfc7b332e4095c0"
            },
            {
                "type": "file",
                "url": "https://pypi.python.org/packages/54/59/4987ae4a4a8be8507af1b213e75a449c05939ab1e0f62b5e90ccea2b51c3/Django-2.0.3.tar.gz",
                "sha256": "769f212ffd5762f72c764fa648fca3b7f7dd4ec27407198b68e7c4abf4609fd0"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "djangoproj",
        "buildsystem" : "meson",
[…]
```

If you have additional dependencies there is a handy tool to generate the necessary json lines: https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak-builder-tools/tree/master/pip

Now you can add the Django project files using the host system.

```
django-admin startproject sample
```

Meson needs to know about the new files so just add `subdir('sample')` to the root meson directory and create new meson files in the subdirectories. The `meson.build` in the sample directory looks like this for me. for the `sample/sample` directory you'd need to adjust the `moduledir` and the `djangoproj_sources`

```
pkgdatadir = join_paths(get_option('prefix'), get_option('datadir'), meson.project_name())
moduledir = join_paths(pkgdatadir, 'djangoproj')
python3 = import('python3')

conf = configuration_data()
conf.set('PYTHON', python3.find_python().path())
conf.set('VERSION', meson.project_version())
conf.set('localedir', join_paths(get_option('prefix'), get_option('localedir')))
conf.set('pkgdatadir', pkgdatadir)

subdir('sample')

djangoproj_sources = [
  'manage.py',
]

install_data(djangoproj_sources, install_dir: moduledir)
```

Now you can set the `command` in the `org.gnome.Djangoproj.json` to `bash` and after pressing launch in the window where otherwise the logs of the program appear there is an interactive shell. There you can explore your newly created flatpak with Django included in the `/app/` directory. If you want to run the Django app you'd do:

```
$ python3 /app/share/djangoproj2/djangoproj2/manage.py runserver
```

you can also write this command in the `command` variable of the `json` file to launch it directly when pressing the "play"-button.

All the other commands do work too- however keep in mind that the environment is in a flatpak and recreated on every rebuild... So nothing that needs to persist can be saved in the flatpak directory.